# Output from sys.stdout in interactive mode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tested sys.stdout.write in interactive mode; why do I get the 'extra' 1 and 2 suffixed to the numbers? If I run the code from a file I get the expected output (1234...) Python 3.3 on a Windows machine

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in range(15):
...     sys.stdout.write(str(i))
...
01
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
102
112
122
132
142
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is *also* echoing the return value of `sys.stdout.write()` call, which is the number of bytes written:

```
>>> import sys
>>> written = sys.stdout.write('10')
10>>> written
2
```

Here the next prompt follows the `'10'` written without a newline.

Or, as a different way of demoing, writting 0 bytes in a loop prints `0` that many times:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     sys.stdout.write('')
... 
0
0
0
```