# Slow printing using time.sleep function

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, sleep

I want to print characters of a string slowly on the terminal on the same line using python3. i used this code.

```
for i in "Hello":
    print(i,end='')
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

this code waits for 0.2 * 5(len of "Hello") secs and prints all the characters at once.when i use sys.stdout.write() function instead of print function, it prints the characters line by line instead of same line. how do i print characters on same line with delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import sys
import time

for c in "Hello":
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush() # <- add this 
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Or use the `flush` parameter in the python 3 `print` function

```
print(c, end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference it still prints every char to new line. i am using ubuntu is that why this doesn't work?

Comment: It should work, can you copy the exact same code you're using?

Comment: I copied your code the sys.stdout.flush() had no effect but flush in print function worked.

Comment: In interactive mode, Python also [prints non-assigned function returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525490/output-from-sys-stdout-in-interactive-mode) to stdout. With `sys.stoud.write`, this is the number of chars printed followed by a `\n` - maybe this is why it doesn't work for you @BalajiS ? To avoid, just assign the return value, like `_ = sys.stdout.write(c)`.